# labels are not being created dynamically one below other

Tags: java, xml

http://ibb.co/hvrdbR    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
       //removing existing panels
        String xmldoc="./src/com/ui/Data.xml";
          try{
            JLabel label2=new JLabel();
            File fXmlFile = new File(xmldoc);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("username");
             for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                 if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                      String text=eElement.getTextContent();
                      System.out.println(text);
                    jPanel7.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                      jPanel7.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                      jPanel7.add(label2);
                     label2.setText(text);
                      label2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,40));
                      label2.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 24));
                      } } }
               catch(Exception ex){
               System.out.println("Database exception : userExists()");
            }
    }

Only label is being created and all the usernames are pasted on it

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration of your loop, `jPanel7.add(label2)` is called once. However, you are using the same `JLabel` instance over and over again.

And what will happen?

`JPanel.add(Component)` is defined in `java.awt.Container.add(Component)`, where it is delegated to [`java.awt.Container.addImpl(Component, Object, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#addImpl-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-int-). And in the code:

```
 /* Reparent the component and tidy up the tree's state. */
 if (comp.parent != null) {
      comp.parent.remove(comp);
      if (index > component.size()) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("illegal component position");
      }
 }
 // ...
 comp.parent = this;
```

Trying to add a `Component` to a `Container` that already contains this `Component` will cause nothing to happen in practice. Therefore, in the end, your `jPanel7` has only one child - `label2`.

And what is the right thing to do?

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String xmldoc="./src/com/ui/Data.xml";
    try {
        // background and layout should be set only once
        jPanel7.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        jPanel7.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        File fXmlFile = new File(xmldoc);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("username");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                String text = eElement.getTextContent();
                System.out.println(text);

                JLabel label2 = new JLabel(text);  // create a new JLabel with the given text
                // set label2's attributes
                label2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,40));
                label2.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 24)); 

                jPanel7.add(label2);  // add it to jPanel7
            } 
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Database exception : userExists()");
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working yet infact it is printing all the retreived usernames from the xml file to a singe label created dynamically

Comment: @shristygupta Could you provide a screenshot? I doubt what you actually mean by "single label", do you want labels to be separated by a line of something?